# Umbraco - Nav items not linking to content

Tags: umbraco

Im very new to Umbraco ... Ive got it installed, when i make my pages in the admin section that all works fine, but when i look at the frontpage, the only page that loads is the default page.

For example, when i click the 'about' button on the frontend, the url is correct but it just reloads the default page.

im not really sure how i would go about debugging this as im very new to this, so i thought i would ask for some help.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Are you running it locally?
Could have been helpful to now which version of Umbraco you are running, and with what template/starter kit.
It's a longshot, but have you tried to publish the entire site?